# Can the union of an ascending sequence of ideals of $R$ be $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian, rngs

I am confused about the equivalence of the different definitions of Noetherian Rings. The confusion essentially stems from the fact that a Noetherian ring need not be finitely generated. Essentially the proof goes like this: If $$I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq I_k \subseteq \cdots $$ is an ascending chain of finitely generated ideals, then $\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}}I_j$ is an ideal which is then finitely generated. Then, all the generators are in some $I_N$ for $N$ sufficiently large, proving the result.

This is clear if $\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} I_j$ is a strict ideal of $R$. I'm not sure if this proof works when $\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} I_j = R$, though. Given a situation like this, where all $I_j$ are strict ideals of $R$, can the union be $R$?

If $R$ has a 1, then definitely not since if $\bigcup_{j} I_j = R$, then $1 \in I_n$ for some $n$ which implies that $I_k = R$ for all $k \geq n$. I'm having trouble seeing why this would be true if $R$ didn't have a 1, though.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To be clear, when you refer to $R$ being finitely generated, you mean as a module over itself?  (That's quite different from being finitely generated as a ring!)  Or maybe this is exactly what you are confused about.

Comment: @EricWofsey I believe I'm thinking about it as finitely generated as a module over itself. That's a good point, though. I didn't know about that distinction. Is the correct term for a "finitely generated ring" $R$ a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}-$algebra over $R$?

Comment: Can you precisely state the exact statement you're trying to prove?  The proof you wrote appears to be a proof that if every ideal in $R$ is finitely generated, then $R$ is Noetherian.  Since $R$ is an ideal in $R$, then by hypothesis $R$ would be finitely generated.

Comment: There is no restriction in the definition of Noetherian for the ideals to be proper ideals, so there is no problem if the union is all of $R$. And yes, the union could be all of $R$: for one thing, one of the ideals could be $R$ itself. If the ring has a unity, then an increasing union of proper ideals must be a proper ideal (that’s how you prove that every ideal in a ring with unity is contained in a maximal ideal). For rings without unity, an increasing union of proper ideals may be the whole thing. But it doesn’t matter; $R$ is generated by $1$ as an ideal/module over itself.

Comment: Note that if $R$ is Noetherian, then $R$ itself is required to be finitely generated as an ideal over itself. The definition does *not* restrict itself to proper ideals.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, that makes sense. I think I was confusing Noetherian modules with rings since Noetherian modules need not be finitely generated. I appreciate the response.

Comment: A Noetherian module is always finitely generated.  Perhaps you are confusing them with Artinian modules.

Comment: @DanielApsley: Huh? Noetherian modules must be finitely generated. A module $M$ is noetherian if and only if *every* submodule (including $M$ itself) is finitely generated. You need to review the definition....

Comment: To answer the question in the title: yes, the union of chain of proper ideals can be the whole thing if $R$ does not have a unity: take $\mathbb{Q}$ as an additive group with zero multiplication. Let $S_1\subsetneq S_2\subsetneq S_3\subsetneq\cdots$ be an increasing chain of sets of primes whose union is all the primes (for instance, $S_k$ can be the first $k$ primes). Let $I_j$ be the set of rationals which, when written in lowest terms, have denominator that is divisible only by primes in $S_j$. Then $I_1\subsetneq I_2\subsetneq\cdots$, $I_j\neq\mathbb{Q}$, $\cup I_j=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Got it. Thanks! That is interesting. I definitely do need to review these definitions since I have made a lot of false assumptions about them here.

Comment: @EricWofsey After some consideration, I figured out what was actually confusing me. Finitely generated modules need not be noetherian.... not the other way around. Thanks for all the help!